# Comparing coefficient of variation

Tags: inference, coefficient-of-variation

I have three sets of data sets each 10 to 20 data points.  I want to test if the coefficient of variation is the same across all the sets. Please suggest relevant methods.

I came across papers by Cabras(2006) and Amiri(2010). One, they look at comparing only two samples and two, my knowledge of simulation / econometric methods is elementary. Are there packages in [R] or Stata that are available to do this?

Comment: CV is very close to variance, so maybe try Bartlett's test of equality of variance across groups.

Comment: An example Bartlett's test used for CVs, with reservations, can be seen here https://sora.unm.edu/sites/default/files/journals/auk/v100n01/p0180-p0187.pdf

Comment: Pairwise tests can be done with https://rdrr.io/rforge/Zar5/man/CV.test.html

Comment: The formula for the Feltz and Miller Asymptotic Test for the Equality of Coefficients of Variation from K Populations is explained here http://anthro.dss.ucdavis.edu/people/jweerken/pdfs/AA2001.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is an R package on CRAN for the Feltz and Miller Asymptotic Test: [cvequality](https://cran.r-project.org/package=cvequality)

That package also has a function for the ‘Modified signed-likelihood ratio test (SLRT) for equality of CVs’ (Krishnamoorthy and Lee 2014).

And it has a [very nice vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvequality/vignettes/how_to_test_CVs.html) showing how to use the functions ;) (disclaimer: I'm the package author)

References:

Feltz, C. J., & Miller, G. E. (1996). An asymptotic test for the equality of coefficients of variation from k populations. Statistics in Medicine, 15(6), 647-658. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8731006

Krishnamoorthy, K., & Lee, M. (2014). Improved tests for the equality of normal coefficients of variation. Computational Statistics, 29(1-2), 215-232. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00180-013-0445-2

Comment: Thanks, These tests confirm if the COV are different. If I want to test for

CV1 > CV2 > CV3, 

do we have some version of post hoc tests? Or can I look at the values of CV of the samples and directly infer?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not currently aware of a post-hoc test. I'd suggest simply plotting the distributions to infer directly, as you can see in the [vignette of the cvequality package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvequality/vignettes/how_to_test_CVs.html)